# Does groupId lose offset position if subscribe method is called twice?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a KafkaConsumer which calls the subscribe method for a particular topic (e.g. topic1). After subscribing to messages from this topic1, I then call the subscribe method for a different topic (e.g. topic2).

At the end, I call commitSync - would both topic1 and topic2 offsets be committed?

Many thanks Stackoverflow-ers :)

Answer (score 0):

When committing offsets using the [`commitSync()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync--) or [`commitAsync()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitAsync--) methods (without passing offsets), only offsets for partitions currently assigned to the Consumer will be committed.

If you were previously subscribed to another topic, this information is not retained in the Consumer and offsets belonging to previous topics are lost.

You either need to commit before changing the subscription or you can retrieve the offsets before changing the subscription by using [`position()`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#position-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-) and manually commit all of them at the end using one the commit methods (for example [`commitSync(offsets)`](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync-java.util.Map-)) that take offsets.